# Can .question-status have a different background-color than blockquote & pre?

Tags: feature-request, questions, design, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

The `.question-status` div, which displays info about the question's duplicate, etc., blends in with other parts of the question.

This screenshot is from StackOverflow:

> [image]

This [confuses users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900784/swift-optional-chaining-with-objective-c-objects?noredirect=1#comment38684216_24900784). Can it be a different color, rather than just bold? Some sites mitigate the problem with a small border, but a vastly different color would help even more.

Isn't this better?

> [image]

Comment: @nicael It affects more than just Stack Overflow; I don't know how many off the top of my head, but the same issue is present in the beta theme, which means it affects dozens. The question should stay here on MSE.

Comment: @Laura point proven :)